# AWS RHEL subscription Vs normal AWS subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, rhel7, subscription

On the new RHEL server on AWS, there is no need to subscribe our own red-hat subscrition to install the package as it's already subscribed by AWS side. I need to know the difference between the AWS RHEL server's redhat subscription and normal redhat subscription.
How the repo's are updating on AWS side(AWS redhat subscription). Are those repo's are trusty?

Answer (score 2):

The official RHEL images in Amazon AWS are provided and maintained by Red Hat themselves.

Red Hat runs its own update infrastructure within every AWS region so that you can get official updates.

From the [Frequently Asked Questions about RHEL on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/partners/redhat/faqs/):

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux on Amazon EC2 is maintained by Red Hat and is identical to the version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux available for installation on physical hardware. AWS customers running Red Hat Enterprise Linux on Amazon EC2 receive access to the base images (AMIs) and updates from Red Hat.

> Red Hat Update Infrastructure (RHUI) is maintained by Red Hat in each AWS region and can be accessed to get regular updates and patches. Red Hat Enterprise Linux instances will have access to the regional repositories to receive incremental updates and is included in all prices.

Note that the *names* of the repositories [differ](https://access.redhat.com/articles/4599971) when using RHUI in AWS, compared to using RHEL on-premise. Mostly they are the same with the addition of the string `rhui`. For instance instead of `rhel-7-server-rpms` the name would be `rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms`

Comment: It would be handy if things like Systems Manager and Inspector agents would be pre-installed, but it says identical to on-premise. Good to have the choice I guess.